# How to add class to a cell depending on the value of another cell in ext js grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

This is what i want to try , i want to highlight a cell according to the value of another column in the same row. I know that the renderer function can style the column on render, but is it possible to access another column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renderer has set of parameters. The third parameter is record.

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record){
    var anotherColumnValue = record.get('anotherColumnDataIndex');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I would hoping there was something similar to getRowClass but unfortunately i think this would have to do. Adding this function to each of the column seems a bit too much though.